# My Sonar default login admin/admin doesn't work after a fresh install of Sonarqube 6.6. Am I missing something here?

Tags: windows, sonarqube

The logs tell me authentication failure which is not much help. Been on this for about a week now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you start with a clean install directory and a new (= empty) database? If you start with a new instance: use SonarQube 6.7 LTS. Add the SonarQube log to your question.

Comment: I have been trying to use PostgresSQL as the database for the past week and I still ran into problems logging into Sonarqube as the default admin. I even went ahead and created a sonar database with user credentials and I still couldn't login to Sonarqube.

Comment: Finally works after downloading 6.7 LTS. Any idea as to why my version wasn't working with the default credentials? Kinda odd but thanks for the help!